# SharePoint Retention Policy - trigger once a year on a particular date - Dynamic year value

Tags: date-time

Looking for some ideas: I need to trigger a retention policy in a particular document library once a year on the same date. The challenge is setting the year dynamically.

Could I use a date\time colum,n using a calculated default value? I am not familiar with the available (calculated) functionality i.e. get i get current year and have the day and month static?

Much appreciated.

Comment: what version of sharepoint?

Comment: Hi - SharePoint version is SPO

Comment: only reason i ask is that you should be using labels in sharepoint online! its a new feature for retention of document thats based on labels assigned to items/documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving with a workflow:
Two columns:
Col1 - date/time default value set - it is used to store the DD/MM
Col2 - the date i want to retention policy to kick off

Workflow to find the difference between created date and Col1 then set Col2; the difference + Col1

Retention policy to kick off on date/time set in Col2